# chrome text rendering busted after some unknown set of upgrades

Tags: apt, nvidia, upgrade, google-chrome, gpu

I restarted my computer for the first time in several months and discovered that chrome's text rendering is totally busted in a few circumstances. (As in, the text is just not there. *Mostly* it's there, but on a few pages the same text is consistently just absent.) Unfortunately, in the interim I upgraded several packages (attempting to install the right tools to fix an unrelated package, and among them was e.g. `ubuntu-desktop`, which installs a boatload of stuff).

Chrome's fora seem to suggest that this is a gpu-related thing, but I see no nvidia-related upgrades in `/var/log/apt/history.*` (and toggling Chrome's hardware acceleration doesn't change anything). Is there any way to just "rewind" a given `apt install` command, so that I can just walk back?

Comment: Please try running Chrome from a newly created user (for testing purposes only) to see if the issue lies in the user profile.

Comment: interesting—I finally created a new user, and the text renders fine. I'm not really sure where to go from here, though.

Comment: restoring settings to default and toggling hardware acceleration don't seem to (either) do anything.

Comment: This is what I have had to do a few times when Chrome borked itself all over my profile. Has happened in to me in both Win10 as well as Ubuntu, so I have gotten devout about backups. See answer following.

Answer (score 0):

1) Back up your old corrupt Chrome profile by making a backup copy of .config/google-chrome in /home .

2) Delete the old corrupt Chrome profile while preserving the copies made in step one above.

3) Copy the new user's Chrome profile into your original userspace.

4) Following https://support.google.com/chrome/search?q=restore+from+corrupt+profile&from_promoted_search=true pull bits and pieces from the backup of the old corrupted profile into the new fresh profile.

Comment: a comprehensive failure:
 - copying in the new user's config didn't fix the rendering issue, so I assume the fault lies outside of chrome and with some other user-specific setting;
 - I fucked up and deleted the old config when I was attempting to restore it. :(